# How to store a count given by a user and the user's choices across activities in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to make a basic app in which I offer the user to add a trackers of various things like water etc. and then he can store how many glasses he has drank so far. However I want it to have saved the information even after the app closes. Please provide a solution.

This is what I've tried so far:-

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnAddTracker;
    //public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyCounter";
    ImageView ivWater;
    TextView tvWaterCount;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = pref.edit();

        if(pref.getBoolean("WaterStatus",false)){
            ivWater.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvWaterCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvWaterCount.setText(pref.getInt("waterCount",0));
        }

        btnAddTracker=findViewById(R.id.btnAddTracker);
        ivWater=findViewById(R.id.ivWater);
        tvWaterCount=findViewById(R.id.tvWaterCount);

        btnAddTracker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,TrackerListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        editor.putInt("waterCount", 8);
        editor.apply();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){

            if(pref.getBoolean("WaterStatus",false)){
                ivWater.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvWaterCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvWaterCount.setText(pref.getInt("waterCount",0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class TrackerListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnAddWaterTracker;
    ImageView ivReturn,ivWater;
    TextView tvWaterStatus;
    boolean WaterStatus;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracker_list);


        ivReturn=findViewById(R.id.ivReturn);
        btnAddWaterTracker=findViewById(R.id.btnAddWaterTracker);
        ivWater=findViewById(R.id.ivWater);
        tvWaterStatus=findViewById(R.id.tvWaterStatus);
        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = pref.edit();
        WaterStatus=pref.getBoolean("waterStatus",false);



        ivReturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent2=new Intent();
                intent2.putExtra("waterStatus",WaterStatus);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent2);
                if(btnAddWaterTracker.getVisibility()==View.GONE) {
                    editor.putBoolean("waterStatus",true);
                    editor.apply();
                }
                TrackerListActivity.this.finish();
                //Intent intent1=new Intent(TrackerListActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                //startActivity(intent1);

            }
        });

        btnAddWaterTracker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                WaterStatus=true;
                btnAddWaterTracker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tvWaterStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //editor.putBoolean("waterStatus",true);
                //editor.apply();


            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of saving informations locally, you could save it on a file using the Json or XML format, you could also use SQLite which are supported by all recent smartphones.

Unfortunately you won't get anyone to code for you on this website, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How can I save the option selected by the user i.e. 'add water tracker' which would display the count of water glasses on the main activity, by SQLite?

Comment: SQLite is basically a database, you can store whatever you want inside and get it in your activities at any time. Search for  some tutorials on how to implement SQLite on an Android app, it's pretty common you'll find a lot of examples